# Blendspace 2D not updating when input direction is changed

Tags: animation, 2d, godot, gdscript, godot4

I'm trying to animate a 2D character using a blendspace2D in an animation tree. I've built a basic state machine where, when the `charge` input is detected while the directional movement is not `(0, 0)`, the state changes to the `DASH` state and remains there until the `charge` button is released, with the animation state changing to the `Dash` animation blendspace2D. However, while in the `DASH` state, the animation doesn't update if I change directions, e.g., if I dash left and then move right while dashing, the animation doesn't change so the character goes backwards. While *not* in the `DASH` state, I have a similar blendspace2D for normal movement, which updates the animations correctly. My code to manage the player character, including the state machine and blendspaces is below.

```
extends CharacterBody2D
class_name Player

@export var ACCELERATION = 17
@export var MAX_SPEED = 100
@export var FRICTION = 100
@export var DASH_SPEED = MAX_SPEED * 1.5
var direction = Vector2.ZERO
enum{
    MOVE,
    DASH,
    CHARGE,
    ATTACK
}
var state = MOVE


@onready var animation_player = $AnimationPlayer
@onready var animation_tree = $AnimationTree
@onready var animation_state = animation_tree.get("parameters/playback")
@onready var sprite_2d = $Sprite2D
#@onready var animation_state = animation_tree.get("parameters/playback")
#var direction_changed = false

var anim_dir = Vector2.ZERO 
 
func _ready():
    animation_tree.active = true

func _process(_delta):
    direction = Vector2.ZERO

    anim_dir.x = Input.get_axis("move_left", "move_right")
    
    anim_dir.y = Input.get_axis("move_up", "move_down")
    direction = anim_dir.normalized()
    

func _physics_process(delta):

    match state:
        MOVE:
            move_state(delta)
        DASH:
            dash_state(delta)
        CHARGE: 
            charge_state(delta)
        ATTACK:
            attack_state(delta)
            
func move_state(delta):

    if direction.length()!= 0:

        if anim_dir.x !=0:
            set_animation_parameters()

        velocity = velocity.move_toward(direction * MAX_SPEED, ACCELERATION)
        move_and_slide()
        animation_state.travel("Move")
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("charge"):
            state = DASH
        
    else:
        velocity = velocity.move_toward(Vector2.ZERO, FRICTION) 
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("charge"):
            state = CHARGE
    
        
        animation_state.travel("Idle")

    

func set_animation_parameters():
    animation_tree.set("parameters/Idle/blend_position", anim_dir)
    animation_tree.set("parameters/Move/blend_position", anim_dir)
    animation_tree.set("parameters/Dash/blend_position", anim_dir)
    
func dash_state(delta):
    if direction.length()>0:
        if anim_dir.x != 0:
            set_animation_parameters()
        velocity = velocity.move_toward(direction * DASH_SPEED, ACCELERATION)
        move_and_slide()
        animation_state.travel("Dash")
    if Input.is_action_just_released("charge"):
        state=MOVE
        
func attack_state(delta):
    pass
func charge_state(delta):
    print("charging...")
    
    if Input.is_action_just_released("charge"):
        state = MOVE
```

As you can see, I set the animation parameters for each state while both moving and dashing and have the `animation_state` travel to `Dash` and `Move` in the same way, yet the latter works and the former doesn't. As far as I can tell it's not because the `Move` animation state gets interrupted by the `Idle` animation state, as I can change directions by holding the input vertically without resetting to the `Idle` animation and it still works.

Here's my animation tree setup:
[image: animation tree for player character]

Here's the `Move` state's blendspace2D where every point on the left is the left moving animation and every point on the right is the right moving animation
[image]

And here's the `Dash` state with the same setup as the `Move` state

[image]

I've tried everything I can think of and have come up empty. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Blend parameter was set incorrectly to be continuous in the Dash state. I set it to be discrete, just as in the Move state's Blend parameter and it worked.